# Function to take class/message hide some fields and return message .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, scramble

Hello i have this message/class for example like this

```
[ProtoContract]
Public class UserMessage
    {
        public override DateTime MessageTimestamp { get; set; }
        public override string MessageId { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(35)]
        public string UserName  { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(34)]
        public string RealName { get; set; }
}
```

And then when i log messages or store them i dont want the `RealName` to be stored or logged anywhere so i would want a function like

```
public UserMessage StripMessage(UserMessage msg){
 //hide RealName from message
  return msg;
}
```

so its very basic function but i just cant figure out how to do this. And i cant put like a `[jsonignore]` or similar on the `UserMessage` class since it comes from another soruce and should not be edited. So some way to scramble/hide fields in a message and return the unhidden ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   public class UserMessage 
    {
        public override DateTime MessageTimestamp { get; set; }
        public override string MessageId { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(35)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(34)]
        public string RealName { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserMessageForLog
    {
        public UserMessageForLog(UserMessage msg)
        {
            MessageTimestamp = msg.MessageTimestamp;
            MessageId = msg.MessageId;
            UserName = msg.UserName;
        }

        public  DateTime MessageTimestamp { get; set; }
        public  string MessageId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

    public LogUserMessage(UserMessageForLog msg)
    {


    }
```

Comment: Would work if i could touch the UserMessage class at all but it comes from a nuget package so i cant add any interface to it or anything at all. I need to handle it all separately from that class